# git-svn clone checkouts wrong repo?

Tags: git-svn

So I am trying to switch to git, by using git-svn. I am having a svn repo called **myrepo** from which I want to clone just the project called **myproject**. The thing is that by running the following command:

`git svn clone path-to-repo/myrepo/myproject --stdlayout --prefix=svn myproject`

the whole repo **myrepo** is cloned rather than just myproject. I tried using -T, -t, -b as well to let git know about the layout of the project, but without any success. I always get the following output:

`Using higher level of URL:  path-to-repo/myrepo/myproject =>   path-to-repo/myrepo`

and tries to clone that one. Am I doing something wrong? It might be that the svn repo layout could be broken or git incompatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I got it working with the usual `-s` switch:

`git svn clone -s <svn_repo_url>`

I also have a few git-svn references that I want to share:

1. http://justaddwater.dk/2009/03/09/using-git-for-svn-repositories-workflow/
2. http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/
3. http://utsl.gen.nz/talks/git-svn/intro.html
4. http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial

Answer (score 74):

You can try the `--no-minimize-url` option.

According to http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html:

> ### --no-minimize-url
>
> When tracking multiple directories (using --stdlayout, --branches, or --tags options), git svn will attempt to connect to the root (or highest allowed level) of the Subversion repository. This default allows better tracking of history if entire projects are moved within a repository, but may cause issues on repositories where read access restrictions are in place. Passing --no-minimize-url will allow git svn to accept URLs as-is without attempting to connect to a higher level directory. This option is off by default when only one URL/branch is tracked (it would do little good).

Comment: I can't find the --minimize-url option. I've tried with git 1.5.4.3 and git 1.6.0.4. Can you give me a little bit more details? Thanks.

Comment: Aah... it's been added in git v1.6.4

Comment: Is there something similar in the versions bellow 1.6.4?

Comment: The minimize-url option set to 1 for all versions below 1.6.4, so I don't think there is anything available for the lower versions.
Any problems in getting the new version?

Comment: Yeah, I have many servers with git bellow 1.6.4 and it would be a pita to get the new version on each one.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and used the --no-minimize-url option. This allowed the clone to succeed, but something like half of the tags were missing. It turns out that prohibiting the clone from going up a level meant it couldn't see a previous repo rename that happened. Once I removed the --no-minimize-url option, the missing tags showed up.

Comment: I tried `--no-minimize-url`. But it still search aggressively for old history and it took a lot of time... My command looks like this: `git svn clone --trunk=<A Folder in SVN Repo> --no-minimize-url --authors-file=authors-transform.txt svn2git`

Answer (score 0):

.gitconfig hack may help, but i dont know how to repopulate after :
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/127528/focus=127776

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you specify a full path to `myproject` it seems like partial paths are not handled well by the *fetch* part of the clone operation.  You may use the colon in that path on Windows (e.g. c:\myproject) (but may not use a colon in the source repository path).

```
git svn clone path-to-repo/myrepo/myproject --stdlayout --prefix=svn myproject
```