# Unable to perform git-svn clone on a sub-repository requiring AD authentication

Tags: git, active-directory, git-svn

I am trying to use git-svn via mysysgit in front of an entreprise subversion repository. This svn repo uses the http protocol, and requires an Active Directory authentication. I can't read on the entire content of the repo, I am just authorized to see my team's projects.

So I am trying the following command :

$ git svn clone http://enterprise:12345/svn/my_team/my_project1/module1 module1 -s --prefix=svn/

where http...my_team is the base url I can access usually with an svn client.

And here is the response from Git :

*Authentication realm http://enterprise:12345 Subversion repository needs authentication against AD
Password for 'yanflea':*

At this step I enter my password and… nothing relevant happens. It keeps warning me about the needed AD authentication, and asks me again and again for my username and password.

I read on several forums that in such a case, the option --no-minimize-url was required. I tried to add it in the command but it didn't change anything. I am surprised because people who explicitly encountered this issue had a more verbose warning than me. Something like

*Using higher level of URL: path-to-repo/myrepo/myproject => path-to-repo/myrepo*
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453416/git-svn-clone-checkouts-wrong-repo)

which indicates clearly that the --no-minimize-url could change something. In my case, first I don't have such a message, and second, the short url seems to be used whatever I add --no-minimize-url option or not. I really don't get it. Any advice is more than welcome.

Yannick.

Comment: What does WWW-Authenticate say?
After a few tests with git I have realized that is has crippled support for auth, especially in enterprise environments compared to svn.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how you got it to work? I'm stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31664132/1995714

Comment: Well.. it was a few years ago. I remember that it finally ended to work by magic with TortoiseGit. But I gave up git-svn a few days later anyway because the cloning took way too long, and failed at 75%.

Comment: Several weeks later, I discovered SmartGit. This GUI client has a its own git-to-svn bridge layer, and works incrdibly faster (it took me just a few minutes to clone the repo). But I doubt it can resolve your initial authentication problem. Give it a try, just in case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up using TortoiseGit, and it did work, strangely, while it sent basically the same command as I did. And now when I do it via msysgit again, it works fine without asking me my credentials anymore at all... The problem just disappeared... Not sure what I did wrong the first time. Not going to spend more time on this issue anyway.